# android: Kill and Activity onClick

Tags: android, onclick, android-activity, destroy

In my android app i am launching an activity using Intent. this activity uses a different layout which has a close ImageButton. I want to set the onClick event to close this activity and go back to the previous activity. i am using the finish() method to achieve this but nothing happens when i click on the close Image Button.

Following is the Code i am using:

To Launch the Activity:

```
public void stOn(){
    Button sb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sb);
    sb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent scIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, St.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(scIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

And to Destroy the Activity:

```
public void stOff(){
    ImageButton pw = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pw);
    pw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            finish(); // Finish Current Activity
        }
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: where are the ImageButton pw located? on the same activity? show the XML please

Comment: are you sure the stOff is called?

Comment: @KurosawaHiroyuki That was it , i forgot to call it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kurosawa Hiroyuki say in comment your function `stOff()` is maybe not called.

That's maybe something you already done but, more generally, in Android, we use to declare all the interface elements (`Button`, `ImageButton`, `EditText`, ...) as fields of the activity and applying `findViewById()` and `setOnClickListener(...)` functions inside the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` function.